# Refresh page after clicking button (ok / cancel)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function clicked() {
  if (confirm('You just clicked the button, click ok or cancel to refresh.')) {
    yourformelement.submit();
    location.reload();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="center" type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent">
    <img src="Playbutton.png" width="800" height="400" alt="submit" onclick="clicked();" />
</button>
```

I want the page to refresh when someone clicks 'ok' or 'cancel'

Comment: it is not clear what that 'location' object is referring to. Have you defined it somewhere? Is it referring to 'window.location'?

Comment: Do you want the page to refresh or the form to submit? What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: Have you tried making it work your self, and if so can you show use what you tried, but are having an issue with?

Answer (score 0):

2 things, first place the onclick handler on the button itself instead of on the image, second you didnt have a reload call in your else statement.

```js
const yourformelement = {};
yourformelement.submit = () => {};


function clicked() {
  if (confirm('You just clicked the button, click ok or cancel to refresh.')) {
    yourformelement.submit();
    location.reload();
  } else {
    location.reload();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="center" type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent" onclick="clicked()">
    <img src="https://kriya-materials.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Play-Button-Transparent-PNG.png" width="400" height="400" alt="submit"/>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use "if" statement

```
function clicked() {
    confirm('You just clicked the button, click ok or cancel to refresh.');
    yourformelement.submit();
    location.reload();
}
```

I recommend using an alert() for only displaying a message.

Comment: Console.log is way better than alert imo

Answer (score -1):

Change

`location.reload();`

to

`window.location.reload();`

and see if that accomplishes what you need.

Answer (score -1):

- your function works good but you just need to store your `confirm()` in variable then check when the user click `ok` it's return `true` and when click `cancel` it's return `false` so if you wants your confirm working in `cancel` and `ok` you need to check the returned value like the following

```
function clicked() {
    var conf = confirm('You just clicked the button, click ok or cancel to refresh.')
    console.log(conf);
     if (conf === true || conf === false) {
           yourformelement.submit();
           location.reload();
       } else {
           return false;
       }
    }
```